# ag-grid detail cell renderer no update data when immutableData is settled

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have an small realtime app.
When in detailCellRendererParams when immutable data property is settled data is not updated

```
detailGridOptions: {
  suppressCellSelection: true,
  immutableData: true,
  getRowNodeId: data => data.id,
```

...

```
  getDetailRowData: ({ successCallback, data }) => {
    successCallback(data.positions)
  }
```

When immutable data property is not defined works well (but cell rendereres are flickering)

In master grid works perfectly